# CGAL 4.9 CGAL_HEADER_ONLY build

Tags: cgal

The following information comes from CGAL download page:

**https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases**

"*The CGAL Open Source Project is pleased to announce the release 4.9
of CGAL, the Computational Geometry Algorithms Library.*"

I have established the variable CGAL_HEADER_ONLY to TRUE in the configuration step from NMAKE, then I have generated the projects for **Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64**. I have not build the libraries, as I understand it is not needed for a header-only use.

Now when I try to build my test application I get the following message:

***LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libCGAL-vc140-mt-4.9.lib'***

There should not be need for .libs in a header only build mode.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: How are you building your application? Are you using cmake? You may need to define a macro so the headers know they are used in header-only mode.

Comment: Thanks for your hint Marc, I have defined the value CGAL_HEADER_ONLY in my visual studio project, and now the CGAL libraries are not searched, solved! The problem now is that is that I get unresolved externals from GMP and MPFR libraries although I have unchecked WITH_GMP and WITH_MPFR in the CMAKE configuration step,

Comment: Finally I have managed to solve it. I have added the variable CGAL_DISABLE_GMP (bool, false) to the CMAKE variables.

Comment: Note that many things in CGAL depend on GMP (or LEDA but you are more likely to have GMP), I would advise against disabling GMP and MPFR...

Comment: Understood and thank you again, still I will include it as soon as my use of CGAL requires it. For the moment I am using boolean operations on generalized polygons and all my tests pass withouth GMP. Soon I will work deeper on learning about arrangements.